# Excel SUMIFS which adds values if column a, or column b contains a specified value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I've had a look around and can't find a solution, and I don't even know if this is possible.

I have two worksheets. I would like `Sheet1!G5` to display the sum of values in `Sheet2!D:D` where `Sheet2!A:A` OR `Sheet2!B:B` is equal to `Sheet1!D5`.

I know its a bit complex, and like I say I don't even know if it is possible, or if `SUMIFS` is the correct formula to be using.

see images below for dummy data in the spreadsheets.. 
basically I want someone to be able to search how many Desktop or how many HP Elitedesk 800 G1 there are (there are more different models of desktops, laptops and monitors etc, but I just don't have them in the dummy data...that's why I want to be able to search both fields.

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my logic is correct you should be able to get away with two separate SUMIF's, one for column A and one for column B, added together:-

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!A:A,D5,Sheet2!D:D)+SUMIF(Sheet2!B:B,D5,Sheet2!D:D)
```

It doesn't look as if it's possible to have the same thing in column A and B for any row, but if so you could make a correction to avoid double-counting as follows:-

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!A:A,D5,Sheet2!D:D)+SUMIF(Sheet2!B:B,D5,Sheet2!D:D)-SUMIFS(Sheet2!D:D,Sheet2!A:A,D5,Sheet2!B:B,D5)
```

The first formula can easily be modified to work with more than two criteria columns (e.g. if you wanted to match on serial number as well), but the second one can't.

To get the total quantity based on more than two columns, where a string can occur more than once in the same row, you would need an array formula like

```
=SUM(SIGN((Sheet2!A2:A10=D5)+(Sheet2!B2:B10=D5)+(Sheet2!C2:C10=D5))*Sheet2!D2:D10)
```

which must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>